# Django comment flagging

Tags: django, comments

I've added comments using the contrib.comments app to one of my django (1.2) models. I've added a flag link to each comment per this example: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/comments/example/#flagging. Flags are being added to the database when I click the flag link.

But.. Now what? There doesn't seem to be a way of viewing which comments are flagged. The flags are not shown in the admin although the admin can flag comments.

At minimum I guess I need a way of showing which comments are flagged and not yet removed. Do I need to implement this myself or is this functionality built into the comment app in some way I have not yet figured out?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add that column to the admin interface when you go in and view comments.  Then you should be able to enable filters in that admin interface and see all comments that are flagged.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter